# Efficient Drop Shadow for GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, winforms, rendering, gdi+

I am drawing some graphics paths with shadows in Windows Forms.

The way I'm doing it is basically:

```
var matrix = new Matrix();  
matrix.Translate(3, 3);
graphicsPath.Transform(matrix);

g.DrawPath(shadowPen, graphicsPath);

graphicsPath.Transform(new Matrix());

g.DrawPath(normalPen, graphicsPath);
```

However, drawing the path seems rather inefficient and have some performance impact on my application. Is there any more efficient away to achieve the same effect?

Could I somehow cache the results from the DrawPath with the normal pen and then just redraw the samething but with a different brush and transform?

Comment: `Is there any more efficient away to achieve the same effect?` - I'm going to get stomped on and flamed an crucified and banned from Stackoverflow forever for this comment, but I must say that winforms is inefficient by design when it comes to dealing with graphics. If you need advanced graphics-intensive capabilites, You should really consider moving to any of the current (< 10 years old), hardware-accelerated, vector-based, more scalable, more performant XAML-based technologies.

Comment: @HighCore: I fully agree with you. However, I can't justify 3 years development time to move to a modern platform on just a performance problem with drawing shadows...

Comment: then don't put shadows in your app. winforms doesn't support any good looking stuff such as `DropShadow`s, `Transparency`, `LinearGradientBrush`es, or even `Animation`s. If you move 1 cm away from the default ugly looking controls in winforms you get performance issues.

Comment: @HighCore: Sorry, but that's not very constructive. If there is no way to make it more efficient just point that out. I'm stuck with winforms and I'm just trying to make the best out of it.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is to place `ElementHost`s with WPF content in your winforms app wherever you need something to look good. It will not be as performant as native WPF but it will surely be faster than trying to do the same in winforms.